# SSIS mapping for commenting line in and out in execute SQL task

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, ssis

In ssis I am trying to add a comment in like this /* and another on the other side with */.

The SQL I have in the execute SQL task is as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('KEY_DWH_RELATIONAL.dbo.PARAM_DIM_CONTACTS') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE KEY_DWH_RELATIONAL.dbo.PARAM_DIM_CONTACTS

CREATE TABLE KEY_DWH_RELATIONAL.dbo.PARAM_DIM_CONTACTS
(
PARAM_ContactId INT,
PARAM_OrganisatoinName NVARCHAR(30),
PARAM_CurrentFlag BIT DEFAULT 1
)

INSERT INTO KEY_DWH_RELATIONAL.dbo.PARAM_DIM_CONTACTS  (PARAM_ContactId, PARAM_OrganisatoinName )




SELECT
CONTACT.[ContactId] AS [ContactId],
CONTACT.DATABASE_NAME AS OrganisationName

FROM dbo.STG_CONTACT_CLIENT AS CONTACT 
inner JOIN dbo.STG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_BASE AS CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
ON CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ParentId = CONTACT.ContactId
WHERE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.AddressNumber = 1
AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ObjectTypeCode = 'ContactBase'


?


AND 




(  



CONTACT.CreatedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,66,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 1)

 or

CONTACT.ModifiedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,66,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 1)

)


?
```

The parameter is a string and has /* and */ respectively for each parameter. I have Mapped it in in ssis mapping as 0 and 1 and using the parameter named in ssis and the datatype as nvarchar. However I have a error as follows: Error: The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator.

However the parameter is a string and the mapping in ssis is set to nvarchar. Can this be done at all or does SSIS only understand actual parameters in the Select, WHERE clause etc?

Comment: Did you try using VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR in parameter mapping ? Alternatively, you can always define variable and do your stuff inside query, like `Declare @var1 varchar(100); Set @var1 = ?`

Comment: I'm PRETTY sure you can't use parameters in this way, but not 100% sure.

Comment: why would you map a comment in? is this for logging?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can use SSIS parameters to dynamically comment out code or make your query "dynamic" in any other way.   I think they can only do what variables in TSQL can do...represent values.

If that is the case, then here's a simple workaround.   Have a single parameter that is either 1 if you want to comment out the stuff after the `AND` or 0 if you don't want to comment it out, and do this:

```
...
WHERE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.AddressNumber = 1
AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ObjectTypeCode = 'ContactBase'
AND (
  1=? OR
    (
      CONTACT.CreatedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,66,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 1)
       or
      CONTACT.ModifiedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,66,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 1)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with dynamic SQL with variables evaluated at runtime. The approach is the following:

- Create a String variable **SQLCommand** with property `EvaluateAsExpression=true` and set its Expression to something like

  ```
  "<Your SQL Start> ... AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ObjectTypeCode = 'ContactBase' " + 
  @[User::AdditionalCondition] + " <your SQL continued>"
  ```
- Create a String variable **AdditionalCondition** and set it to NULL or value `" AND <your condition> "` based on condition on your flow
- At Execute SQL task, set variable **SQLCommand** as the command source

Work behind is the following -- package will set **AdditionalCondition** variable at runtime based on logic you programmed. At Execute SQL Command, package will evaluate **SQLCommand** variable injecting **AdditionalCondition** as defined in the variable expression.